# Neo4J : Database failed to start. Try to install-service fail

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, neo4j

I try to use Neo4J on Windows10.
I've dowloaded the Desktop App (after create an account).

If I create a new Project + Database, there an error :

```
Database failed to start: DB closed with exit code 1. Check the logs
```

The log :

```
AVERTISSEMENT: This command does not appear to be running with administrative rights.  Some commands may fail e.g. Start/Stop
```

and

```
[2017-11-16 16:59:52:0877] [error] DB database-755f4ed3-c6be-4387-985b-191d743303ba closed with exit code 1
```

So, I launch a console (Cmd and PowerShell) with administrator rights :

```
C:\Users\ME\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-755f4ed3-c6be-4387-985b-191d743303ba\current\bin>neo4j status
The Neo4j Windows Service 'neo4j' is not installed

C:\Users\ME\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-755f4ed3-c6be-4387-985b-191d743303ba\current\bin>neo4j install-service
Invoke-Neo4j : Un objet n'existe pas à l'emplacement spécifié C:\Users\F9E13~1.PES.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 403
+ ... rrent\bin\Neo4j-Management.psd1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4j install-service)
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-Neo4j
```

and :

```
 .\neo4j.bat start
Invoke-Neo4j : Impossible de trouver un service assorti du nom « neo4j ».
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 403
+ ... 43303ba\current\bin\Neo4j-Management.psd1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4j start)
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-Neo4j
```

and :( :

```
 .\neo4j.bat console
Invoke-Neo4j : Un objet n'existe pas à l'emplacement spécifié C:\Users\F9E13~1.PES.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 403
+ ... 303ba\current\bin\Neo4j-Management.psd1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4j console)
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-Neo4j
```

Any Idea ?

Thanks,
Fabrice

Comment: Can you try to install the desktop in a path without spaces ?

Comment: I'm on Windows10, and I can't choose the installation folder. I've uninstalled the Desktop, and re-installed in the same place (.../AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Desktop/...). I know I can choose the databases folder, but not the installation path, isn'it ?

Comment: There's a problem. I've change the folders, but, when I launch the Desktop, it re-create himself a folder (.../Neo4j Desktop/...) ; even if I change to .../Neo4jDesktop/...)

Comment: And, It download, each time, Neo4J, java, etc... :(